# LLDB remote debbuging between two macOS

Tags: macos, remote-debugging, lldb

I have been trying for hours to get a simple program to be debug remotely.

On the remote macOS, I cannot build it as it is an older macOS that cannot have the latest Xcode to build without any errors.

My plan was to build on the development machine, then use LLDB to debug it remotely.

On the remote machine I have run `debugserver "DEV_IP:1234"`
On the dev machine:

```
lldb
platform select remote-macosx
platform connect connect://REMOTE_IP:1234
file a.out
run
```

I do have this log on the remote machine `Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.`

However, it always fails with the following error:

`error: invalid host:port specification: 'REMOTE_IP'`

If anyone has an idea on how I could remotely debug without having to install the binary on the remote machine AND without getting started before attaching as the process early crashes.